# Why LOGIN7 returns empty reply using TDS protocol

Tags: sql-server-2012, tds

I am using Tabular Data Stream protocol to login to SQL Server.
The PreLOGIN is successful and returns message with as 4.  Where as the LOGIN 7 returns empty message. And server closes the connection.

How to make a successful login using LOGIN 7 ?.
What are the minimum requisite to use LOGIN 7 ?.

Do we require to use any details from PRE LOGIN messages in LOGIN 7 ?.
Where i can find the samples for a proper PRELOGIN and LOGIN 7 using Tabular Data Stream protocol.

This is the server response from the PRELOGIN client request:

```
04 01 00 2B 00 00 01 00 00 00 1A 00 06 01 00 20
00 01 02 00 21 00 01 03 00 22 00 00 04 00 22 00
01 FF 0C 00 17 88 00 00 00 00 00
```

Thank you ..............

Comment: Generally, a session is closed due to a message sequence violation or structurally invalid message. You'll need to check the encryption option returned in the server `PRELOGIN` response to determine if another `PRELOGIN` is required for TLS negotiation prior to `LOGIN7`. See the [protocol spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/8bfcbcd2-1baf-4792-8fff-86a63a9e90fa).

Comment: Server accepts PRELOGIN message(0x12) and send reply 
PRELOGIN response(0x04) with packet length 43. 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/9420b4a3-eb9f-4f5e-90bd-3160444aa5a7).

How to check, if another PRELOGIN is required for TLS negotiation prior to LOGIN7 ?.  
Where i can find a sample for TLS negotiation ?.
Is there any places for  the samples....

Comment: The option tokens in the server response indicate if a subsequent PRELOGIN is needed. If you need help understanding those option tokens, I suggest you add the 43-byte PRELOGIN response to your question.

Comment: Found some [examples](http://klonkers.blogspot.com/2015/01/making-something-useful-out-of-ms-tds.html) that also might help you.

Comment: Thank you for the support and example.  The response in hex and text is given below...
4
1
0
2B
0
0
1
0
0
0
1A
0
6
1
0
20
0
1
2
0
21
0
1
3
0
22
0
0
4
0
22
0
1
FF
C
0
17
88
0
0
0
0
0

Text
-----

 +          !  "   " � �

Comment: Where to get examples for LOGIN7 ?.

Comment: Used the solution from github.com/Azure/SQL-Connectivity-Check. 
Login7 did not work. Server returns empty response.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/245979/how-is-tds-authentication-data-protected